# Standard location for external web (Grails) application config files on linux

Tags: linux, grails, ubuntu, configuration-files

Is there a standard location on Linux (Ubuntu) to place external config files that a web application (Grails) uses?

UPDATE:  Apparently, there is some confusion to my question. The way Grails handles config files is fine.  I just want to know if there is a standard location on linux to place configuration files.  Similar to how there is a standard for log files (/var/log).  If it matters, I'm talking about a production system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux configuration files typically reside in /etc. For example, apache configuration files live in /etc/httpd. Configuration file not associated with standard system packages often live in /usr/local/etc.

So I'd suggest **/usr/local/etc/my-grails-app-name/**. Beware that this means you can't run two different configurations of the same app on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a standard location. You usually define the location for your external config files via the `grails.config.locations` property in config.groovy.

#### EDIT

After reading your comment, I suppose the standard locations would be:

- Somewhere on the classpath

OR

- In the `.grails` folder in your home directory.

As these are the defaults in `config.groovy` file.

```
grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
                            "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
                            "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
                            "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"]
```

Comment: Yes, I kno *where* to define them.  Just didn't know if there was a standard location for where these might live.  There are standards for log files, etc.

Comment: Why would I have a .grails folder on a production system?  And if they are external, why would they be in my classpath?

Comment: @Gregg This is your first mention of a production system in this question so maybe you should have been more specific in your original question. 
As for your second question, You should know that a `classpath` is just a list of `paths` that the JVM or app searches for required classes and other files.
This path can be anywhere(read `external`) on a file system. So yes, your classpath can be external to your project!

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin [Standardized external configuration for your app](http://grails.org/plugin/external-config) which you might find useful if the `grails.config.locations` parameter is insufficient.

Comment: It's not that what grails provides is insufficient.  I just wanted to know if there was a standard location on linux for configuration files.  It doesn't even have to be Grails specific.